# Is it possible to post code taken from the .net framework and modified online?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

I used reflector to view the code of the generic dictionary collection (Dictionary<TKey, TValue>) and modified that code to make it thread safe. I want to post this code on my blog so others can review it (and tell me if I did something wrong) and also use it in their projects if they want. Legally speaking, am I allowed to do so? I modified the original code heavily (and only took a few methods from the original code not the whole thing) but the base code is still the same, could be there any potential legal issues if I do this?

Note:
Just in case some will point me to implementations of a thread safe dictionary, I know that there are already implementations of a thread safe dictionary using ReaderWriterLockSlim but I don't want any locking when reading (only when writing), besides I'm using .net 2.0 not 3.5 so I can't use ReaderWriterLockSlim anyway, also I read somewhere that the performance of ReaderWriterLock in 2.0 is very poor so I don't want to use that.

Comment: The more interesting article would be how you lock writes but not reads and how you deal with iterators.

Comment: IMO, it is artificial to make a dictionary thread-safe internally; it is more often necessary to be thread-safe spanning a set of related operations (ContainsKey/Add/Remove for example). Unless you change it to accept delegates (or similar), I'm not personally convinced how useful it would be.

Comment: @nobugz, I could tell you how if I could contact you, if you're interested to know how email me ...

Comment: @Marc, why would you ever use something like ContainsKey() with Add()? just use the indexer, ie. dic[key] = value;
In case you have special needs (don't want the value to be replaced), you could add a new method, something like AddIfNotExists() and make it thread safe, this is what I would do.

Comment: Hi Waleed, could you either request more informations, or accept an answer?

Answer (score 12):

Microsoft's Dictionary source code is governed by [a modified version of the Microsoft Reference Source License](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframeworklicense.aspx), which basically only allows you to read the code. So no, you're definitely not allowed to redistribute modified code under this license.

On the other hand, you can take [Mono's implementation of Dictionary<K,V>](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs?content-type=text%2Fplain&view=co) and modify it to suite your needs, as it is licensed under the MIT/X11. It performs [quite well compared to the one in .net](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/10/29/collections-and-performances.aspx).

Comment: +1 for a nice answer that softens the blow by providing an alternative

Comment: Nice point on the Mono alternative!  Also, the reference source license is only valid if you download the source specifically.  If it's decompiled from the framework, the .NET Framework EULA is the license in question...

Comment: Reed: yep. In both case anyway, it's a no go :)

Answer (score 6):

Unless the .NET framework is released in source form and under a license that allows you to make and distribute such modifications (typically referred to as derivative works) then, no, you are now allowed to do this.

While source to parts of the .NET framework [have been released](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/03/releasing-the-source-code-for-the-net-framework-libraries.aspx) they are only available under a [reference license](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/sharedsource/referencesourcelicensing.mspx). Straight from that page;

> The Microsoft Reference Source License
>   (Ms-RSL) is the most restrictive of
>   the Microsoft source code licenses.
>   The license prohibits all use of
>   source code other than the viewing of
>   the code for reference purposes. The
>   intent of this license is to enable
>   licensors to release, for review
>   purposes only, more sensitive
>   intellectual property assets.

If you wish to provide your own thread-safe dictionary collection than that's fine and definitely a noble goal, but you cannot base it on something that you do not have the right to modify.

Answer (score 4):

First off, consult a lawyer - I'm not one, so take what I say with a grain of salt.  Also, this advice will be US/Western Europe centric, as those are the laws I know best.

That being said....

Technically, you are not allowed to even do what you did.  The .NET Framework is licensed as a supplement to the Operating System.  If you read the EULA for .NET 2.0, it includes:

`Microsoft Corporation (or based on where you live, one of its affiliates) licenses this supplement to you.  If you are licensed to use Microsoft Windows operating system software (the “software”), you may use this supplement.  You may not use it if you do not have a license for the software.  You may use a copy of this supplement with each validly licensed copy of the software.`

The license for Windows Vista/XP determines your legal rights according to the EULA that comes with the .NET Framework.

This prevents you from doing this.  In particular:

From the Windows Vista license agreement:

`You may not`

· work around any technical limitations in the software

· reverse engineer, decompile or disassemble the software, except and only to the extent that applicable law expressly permits, despite this limitation

These are their first two points - both of which it sounds like you are trying to do.  Redistribution is included later in the terms.  For complete details, [read the license of your OS](http://www.microsoft.com/about/legal/useterms/default.aspx).